# PHP: Read MusicBrainz tags from AAC files

Tags: php, aac, musicbrainz

does anyone know a simple way to read the MusicBrainz tags (MBID for track, release and artist) from an AAC file?

If there's an external binary it must be command line. This will only be run on my mac.

I've tried the obvious things:

- Googling for the direct problem.
- Googling for more generic solutions like "command line musicbrainz"

There are many programs out there that are GUI, but none that I can find that a pure command line implementations. I do not need write capability, just reading of tags.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe looking at the source of http://musicbrainz.org/doc/phpbrainz would be of some help?

Comment: @plod That is only to query the webservice, that part I can do already. It's getting the tags out of the physical files that's tricky.

Comment: To my knowledge, you send the metadata from the audio file to a query in the MusicBrainz api, (Author, Title) and request the results. 

See https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/JSON_Web_Service for more info.